# Limit number of rows show per page in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pagination

Where can  I go to find a tutorial on how to limit the number of rows that rails shows in the view?

A pagify option would also be cool... thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should visit this site https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari 
Kaminari 
A Scope & Engine based, clean, powerful, customizable and sophisticated paginator for Rails 3

Answer (score 2):

Try will_paginate gem .

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Answer (score 2):

The [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_pagination.html) is often nice to have an overview of the gems for a particular feature.